# Search and replace for a specific string in multiple lines of a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, text

I have a text file in which I want to search for the number 255 in every line to replace it with the number 0. It is to be noted that the number are written in the text file as strings. I want to skip the first 13 lines, since there is text in these 13 lines.

A part of the text file is shown below:

```
F2G_DIM 3
F2G_VERSION 1
F2G_LOCATION 0 0 0.5
F2G_ROTATION 0
F2G_ORIGIN 0 0 0
F2G_NB_NODES 300 150 50
F2G_LAGS 10 10 1
F2G_ORDER +Y +X +Z
F2G_NB_VARIABLES 1
F2G_VARIABLE_1 Facies
F2G_UNDEFINED_1 255
F2G_VALUES 
2
1
2
255
2
255
2
2
5
9
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I use windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first questions you can use logical indexing to find and substitute the `255`

```
pattern = 255; %Number to find
array = randi(10,10,1); %Some array
array([4,8,9]) = 255;

array(array==pattern) = 0; %Substitute values
```

For the second question, you can use [`dlmread`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html?searchHighlight=dlmread&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to load in the data. It allows you to specify a header to ignore.

```
data = dlmread('file.csv',' ',13,0);
```

where `13` is the number of rows to ignore and `0` is the number of columns to ignore.

In total you have something like:

```
pattern = 255; %Pattern
data = dlmread('file.csv',' ',13,0); %Load
data(data==pattern) = 0; %Substitute values
```

Comment: Thank you! Using this I got my answer.

Comment: An additional question, Is there an easy way to make all the "255" into the letter "U", instead of a "0"?

Comment: You cannot have an array of mixed type. Either it is numbers or it is characters. Ways to circumvent includes turning it into a cell-array or alternatively you can use the ASCII number for `"U"` which is 85, though it will still say 85 in the array.